# What is the process to store echoed words in one field of MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

What is the process to store echoed words in one field of MySQL database. Say in this case,

Depends on the condition the following words

```
   *Conformity
   Tradition
   Benevolence
   Universalism
   Self-Direction
   Stimulation
   Hedonism
   Achievement    
   Power
   Security*
```

will be displayed on the screen, but how to store in the database. So I would like to store the results on one field. Say depends on my choice only Conformity, Tradition,Benevolence, Universalism came, So I would like to store it

```
  ===========
  | Result  |
  ===========
  Conformity
  Tradition
  Benevolence
  Universalism
```

This is per the suggestion from stackoverflow user I changed my code as below but not getting anything displayed on the screen nor in the database.

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<?php
// create a variable
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
$department=$_POST['department'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$sex=$_POST['sex'];


function checkResults($rules, &$finalResult) {
    foreach($rules as $word => $rule) {
        $valid = true;
        foreach($rule as $answer) {
            $fieldname = 'answer'.$answer;
            $valid = $valid && (isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && ($_POST[$fieldname]) == 'yes');
        }
        if ($valid) {
            $finalResult .= (empty($finalResult) ? '' : '|') . $word;
            echo $word . '<br />';
        }
    }
}

$rules = array(
    'Conformity'     => array(7,16,28,36),
    'Tradition'      => array(9,20,25,38),
    'Benevolence'    => array(12,18,27,33),
    'Universlism'    => array(3,8,19,23,29,40),
    'Self Direction' => array(1,11,22,34),
    'Stimulation'    => array(6,15,30),
    'Hedonism'       => array(10,26,37),
    'Achievement'    => array(4,13,24,32),
    'Power'          => array(2,17,29),
    'Security'       => array(5,14,21,31,35),
);

$finalResult = '';
checkResults($rules, $finalResult);

echo "\$finalResult=$finalResult<br />";

mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO employee(first_name,last_name,department,email,location,sex,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,answer6,answer7,answer8,answer9,answer10,answer11,answer12,answer13,answer14,answer15,answer16,answer17,answer18,answer19,answer20,answer21,answer22,answer23,answer24,answer25,answer26,answer27,answer28,answer29,answer30,answer31,answer32,answer33,answer34,answer35,answer36,answer37,answer38,answer39,answer40,finalResult)
VALUES('$first_name','$last_name','$department','$email','$location','$sex','$answer1','$answer2','$answer3','$answer4','$answer5','$answer6','$answer7','$answer8','$answer9','$answer10','$answer11','$answer12','$answer13','$answer14','$answer15','$answer16','$answer17','$answer18', '$answer19','$answer20','$answer21','$answer22','$answer23','$answer24','$answer25','$answer26','$answer27','$answer28','$answer29','$answer30','$answer31','$answer32','$answer33','$answer34','$answer35','$answer36','$answer37','$answer38','$answer39','$answer40','$finalResult')");

if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) > 0){
    echo "<p>Thank you for your survey!</p>";
    echo "<p>You have the following value and ethics</p>";
    echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Please share your Public Timeline status by CLICKING here</a>";

   $myArray = unserialize($row['finalResult'];

   foreach($myArray as $word){
      echo $word . <br>;
   }
} else {
   echo "Data NOT Added<br />";
   echo mysqli_error ($db);
}   

//  $fromDatabase = $row['finalResult'];
$words = explode('|', $fromDatabase);
echo '<br />From database: <br />';
foreach($words as $n => $word) {
    echo $word . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: You could concatenate the words, delimited by a pipe (|) character before storing it. When read again _$words = explode('|',$fromdb);_ would expand them again.

Comment: I would like to know is it possible to store the first echoed word in a variable say FinalResult and then append the next echoed word on the FinalResult. At last I can store FinalResult in the database.

Comment: Yes, there are several approaches: you could add the words to an array, and then _serialize()_ or _implode()_ to create a string. When read from the database you could use _unserialize()_ or _implode()_ respectively to create an array again. Alternatively you could concatenate the words thru an own function like in my answer below.

Comment: I updated my answer, puzzling it all together. You'll see that I've streamlined all the test for "yes". Note: I have not tested the database accesses.

Comment: No not getting the answer, I double checked the database connectivity.

Comment: So, please check the results from the database connection and the queries. E.g.: did you test the what _mysqli_query();_ is returning (true/false)? That's hard for us to do without installing your database completely, sorry. All the other code of our answers is tested and works well.

Comment: I just saw that I have left _$serialized_ in my version of the database query; changed now to _$finalResult_. Try it again.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP, however. Would you mind editing your question and removing the asp-classic tag?

Comment: @hherger, yes that I did already, but no help!

Comment: @hherger, I edited the code, please have a look.

Comment: i have a male/female.php page from where it will redirect to process.php. So in the male/female.php page i have the radio buttons to choose the yes/no options. for your ready reference  http://pastebin.com/iHAR9B97

Comment: And what do you where do with the data you inserted into the database?

Comment: Dint get the meaning. Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've puzzled it all together for you.
The code is tested, including database access. The values from the form have been simulated (noted in the code).

### HTML Form

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<form id="questions" name="questions" action="test1.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<h3>1. Thinking up new ideas and being creative is important to him. He likes to do things in his own original way.</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="no" />No
<br/>


<h3>2. It is important to him to be rich. He wants to have a lot of money and expensive things.</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="no" />No
<br/>


<h3>3. He thinks it is important that every person in the world be treated equally. He believes everyone should have equal opportunities in life.</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="answer3" value="no" />No
<br/>

<h3>4. It's very important to him to show his abilities. He wants people to admire what he does.</h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer4" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="answer4" value="no" />No
<br/>
<input id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

### Code

```
<?php 
// include 'database.php';
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'anupaoe4_fbtest', 'satellite098', 'anupaoe4_fbtest', 3306, '');
if (!$db) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Insert into database
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

$first_name = !empty($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '???';
$last_name  = !empty($_POST['last_name'])  ? $_POST['last_name']  : '???';
$department = !empty($_POST['department']) ? $_POST['department'] : '???';
$email      = !empty($_POST['email'])      ? $_POST['email']      : '???';
$location   = !empty($_POST['location'])   ? $_POST['location']   : '???';
$sex        = !empty($_POST['sex'])        ? $_POST['sex']        : '???';

// Simulation of ansers
// $_POST['answer12'] = 'yes';
// $_POST['answer18'] = 'yes';
// $_POST['answer27'] = 'yes';
// $_POST['answer33'] = 'yes';
// $_POST['answer10'] = 'yes';
// $_POST['answer26'] = 'yes';
// $_POST['answer37'] = 'yes';

// Rules apply when the user has answered all the corresponding "answer99" questions with "yes".
$rules = array(
//  "word"           => list of answer numbers, corr. to e.g. "answer7", "answer16", etc.
    'Conformity'     => array(7,16,28,36),
    'Tradition'      => array(9,20,25,38),
    'Benevolence'    => array(12,18,27,33),
    'Universlism'    => array(3,8,19,23,29,40),
    'Self Direction' => array(1,11,22,34),
    'Stimulation'    => array(6,15,30),
    'Hedonism'       => array(10,26,37),
    'Achievement'    => array(4,13,24,32),
    'Power'          => array(2,17,29),
    'Security'       => array(5,14,21,31,35),
);

// Check answers, create corresponding list of "words",
// Create db field names and values from the user's answers
function checkResults($rules, &$finalResult, &$names, &$values) {
    $ansvals = array();
    foreach($rules as $word => $rule) {
        $valid = true;
        foreach($rule as $answer) {             // Check a rule 
            $fieldname = 'answer'.$answer;
            $valid = $valid && (isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && ($_POST[$fieldname]) == 'yes');
        }

        if ($valid) {                           // Rule is fulfilled
            $finalResult .= (empty($finalResult) ? '' : '|') . $word;
            $ansvals[$fieldname] = 'yes';
            echo $word . '<br />';
        }
        for ($xi=1; $xi<=numanswers; $xi++) {   // For all the other answers...
            $fieldname = 'answer'.$xi;
            if (!isset($ansvals[$fieldname])) {
                $ansvals[$fieldname] = (isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && ($_POST[$fieldname])) ? $_POST[$fieldname] : 'no';
            }
        }
    }
    // Create name and value parts of the query statement for all the answers
    foreach($ansvals as $fname => $fvalue) {
        $names  .= ",$fname";
        $values .= ",'$fvalue'";
    }
    unset($ansvals);
}

define('numanswers',40);
$finalResult = '';
$names       = '';
$values      = '';
// Check the answers
checkResults($rules, $finalResult, $names, $values);
// Prepare the names and values for the query
$names  = 'id,first_name,last_name,department,email,location,sex' . $names . ',finalResult';
$values = "DEFAULT,'$first_name','$last_name','$department','$email','$location','$sex'" . $values . ",'" . $finalResult . "'";

// Perform query inserting record into the database
$query = "INSERT INTO employee ($names) VALUES ($values)";
echo "\$finalResult=$finalResult<br />";  // FOR TESTING ONLY
echo "\$query=$query<br />";              // FOR TESTING ONLY
$queryresult = mysqli_query($db,$query);
if ($queryresult===false) { // We errored inserting the record into the database
    die ('ERROR WHILE INSERTING INTO DATABASE, ' . mysqli_errno($db) . ': ' . mysqli_error($db) );
}
$myID = mysqli_insert_id ($db);
echo "\$myID=$myID<br />";

// Send feedback to the user
if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) > 0){
    echo "<p>Thank you for your survey!</p>";
    echo "<p>You have the following value and ethics</p>";
    echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Please share your Public Timeline status by CLICKING here</a>";
} else {
    echo "Data NOT Added<br />";
    echo mysqli_error ($db);
}
mysqli_close($db);


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Read from database
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

//  Re-open the database
//  Select the previously inserted record and display the finalResult field
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'anupaoe4_fbtest', 'satellite098', 'anupaoe4_fbtest', 3306, '');
if (!$db) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee where id=$myID";
echo "\$query=$query<br />";              // FOR TESTING ONLY
$queryresult = mysqli_query($db,$query);

if ($queryresult===false) { // We errored reading the record again
    die ('ERROR WHILE SELECTING A PREVIOUSLY INSERTED DATABASE RECORD, ' . mysqli_errno($db) . ': ' . mysqli_error($db) );
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($row); echo '</pre>';
    $words = explode('|', $row['finalResult']);
    echo '<br />From database: <br />';
    foreach($words as $n => $word) {
        echo $word . '<br />';
    }
}
mysqli_free_result($queryresult);
mysqli_close($db);
```

### Database Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `department` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `location` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sex` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
    `answer1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `answer2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
[...]
    `answer39` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `answer40` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `finalResult` varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### Notes

- The code contains 2 parts (INSERT and SELECT)
  These belong to different steps within a session: SELECT where the form is created and the data is shown, INSERT where the user's data is taken from the form and is inserted into the database.
- All the "answer99" fields from the form are handled by the function **checkResults()**. This function...

  - Takes in the rules (in the array *$rules*) to decide which "words" are valid.
  - Concatenates the words found giving *$finalResult*.
  - Dynamically creates for all "answer99" fields the names (*$names*) and values (*$values*) to be used for the INSERT query.
    The *$names* and *$values* variables are then completed by the other database fields and values. The number of "answer99" fields is defined by the statement *define('numanswers',40);*
- The INSERT part is fully implemented while the SELECT part selects the last inserted record and only displays the *finalResult* field after.
- The corresponding HTML form used for testing the INSERT part is shown above.

Comment: I have used as you said , but nothing effect on the screen as wel as on the db here the code, http://pastebin.com/dcNkd8S6

Comment: in this case, is the answer are stored in database ?

Comment: Yes, as long as the database handling works ok, the answers, the generated words (_finalResult_), and the other fields of the form as of your code are inserted into the database. I once more updated my answer. I have created a form based on yours for testing. Everything is ok (the database accesses have NOT been tested, though).

Comment: I dont know where I am wrong. Still not able to insert it in the DB

Comment: This is my male.php http://pastebin.com/Ufd2qSeD and process.php http://pastebin.com/yRdn0n7R After I clicked on the Submit button it shows nothing on the screen neither on database

Comment: is the PDO require here?

Comment: No. It is not important how you are accessing the database and are issueing your query. _mysqli\_query($db,$query);_, as in your case is ok. (This is true for the INSERT part as well as the SELECT part, which I have not implemented in my answer). I suggest either one: (1) Try the code without database, just assume values for the _$\_POST['answer99']_ parameters or (2) publish your database (CREATE) and your _database.php_ file here (username and password do not matter) so we can try outselves with the database connection. Otherwise it's impossible to help you take off.

Comment: here is my database.php file http://pastebin.com/QrDZgDND. Publishing database means I am not getting

Comment: and these are my database fields http://screenshot.co/#!/a7a42d9886 and http://screenshot.co/#!/1f3f198cae

Comment: So, I have (the last time) added code to my answer: Now it contains the (corrected, there were a couple of errors in your code) SQL statements. In my example the database is opened inline; but, of course, you can use your include file. The code is tested as described in the answer. The database structure might not be exactly what you showed, because I had it created before. Look at the code, try to throughly understand it, and, if necessary make your changes.

Comment: Yes just now I found the mistake in the code, if i assigned the insert sql statement in variable it does nothing after that what I did is  mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO employee ($names) VALUES ($values)"); Any way @hherger Thanks a lot.

/*$query = "INSERT INTO employee ($names) VALUES ($values)";*/

Comment: There were some more mistakes ... believe me. So, you might wish to accept my answer - right?

Comment: Need to know, Is there a way to compute the  values like Conformity, Tradition etc. by taking the mean values of the answers like Conformity' => mean of (7,16,28,36) etc and then store it in the database?

Comment: Can you kindly explain me the working flow of the code plz http://pastebin.tlhiv.org/Mokvvpnd. When I tried with the  6 options instead of yes/no, I am not getting the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new table which holds all the results. Instead of having a finite amount of columns in your 'employee' table.

Your new table would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `result`
`result_id` INT(11),
`employee_id` INT(<int-length-of-employee-id>),
`result` VARCHAR(<max-length-of-a-result>)
FOREIGN KEY (`result_id`) REFERENCES `employee`(`employee_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of words, serialize the array, and insert the serialized array in the db.

Example:

```
$arrayOfWords = array('Tradition','Benevolence','Universalism'); //the array

$serialized = serialize($arrayOfWords); // this is a string now: a:3:{i:0;s:9:"Tradition";i:1;s:11:"Benevolence";i:2;s:12:"Universalism";}
```

Then, when you output from db, you can unserialize the field and you'll get your array back:

```
$myArray = unserialize($row['fieldName'];

foreach($myArray as $word){
   echo $word;
}
```

Comment: How to store the result in $arrayOfWords?  As there are 11 category, but depends on the user input out of 11 say 5 are correct and need to store the 5 in the database.

Comment: Don't store **$arrayOfWords**, you should store the **$serialized** variable in the database.

Comment: but before that i need to construct the $arrayOfWords from the if-else condition.

Comment: Use `array_push($arrayOfWords, $userInput);` to store user inputs in your array, then follow the instructions above.

Comment: `if (!empty ($userInput) { array_push($arrayOfWords, $userInput);  }` got it?

Comment: I have added a code, but not getting the data displayed in the screen nor in the database.

Comment: You should have a single field named "answers" where you insert `$finalResult` variable, or my `$serialized` variable, not all those answers fields. If you can't solve it, i can help you in about 12 hours on Skype.

Comment: So I should not add the function addtoResult($finalResult, $Conformity); in the if() statement.

Comment: No longer. I have replaced it by a function _checkResults()_ which creates the _$finalResult_ variable plus the _names_ and _values_ parts of all the _answers_ for use in the query statement. You should have all together from my answer for the process of INSERTING into the database. Missing is - obviously - the SELECT statement, since this would anyway be executed in a different step of the session (where the form is created). If you still have problems, you should publish all your code plus the database structure (CREATE TABLE).